# Evaluate $\iint y^2dxdy$ ($y$ varies from $\sqrt{1−x^2}$ to 0 and $x$ varies form 1 to 0) by changing order of integration

Tags: calculus, integration

Here $x^2+y^2=1$, $x=\sqrt{(1−y^2}$
hence $x$ varies from $0$ to $\sqrt{1−y^2}$
and   $y$ varies from 0 to 1.

$$\iint y^2dxd= ∫y^2x\,dy =∫y^2\sqrt{1−y^2}dy$$

then I am at lost to proceed. The answer is $π/16$ in the book. Theres no procedure in my book just the answer.

Comment: Hint: Polar coordinates, as suggested by $x^2 + y^2 = 1.$

Comment: Hint: as others have noted, you're integrating over a quarter-circle viz. $\int_0^1r^3dr\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^2\theta d\theta$ since $dxdy=rdrd\theta,\,y=r\sin\theta$. Now evaluate each of these integrals.

Comment: You are going alright so far by finding: $\int_0^1 y^2\sqrt{1-y^2}dy$. Now make the substitution $y=sin\theta$.

Comment: You can use the same method as in my previous answer. $y=\sin t$. And do not forget the limits when writing definite integral.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Note that the integration area is the first quarter of the unit circle

Answer (score 0):

Let us denote by $Q$ the quarter disk
$$
Q=\{\ (x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\ :\ 0\le x,y\le 1\ ,\ x^2+y^2\le 1\ \}\ .
$$
Then we have to compute the integral $J$ of $(x,y)\to y^2$ on $Q$. Note that the change of variables $(x,y)\to (y,x)$ shows that we can equivalently compute the integral of $(x,y)\to x^2$ on $Q$. Putting all together, and passing to polar coordinates $(r,t)$, we have the one-liner:
$$
J = \frac 12\iint_Q(x^2+y^2)\; dx\; dy =\frac 12\int_0^1 r^2\cdot r\;dr\int_0^{\pi/2}dt
=\frac 12\cdot\frac 14\cdot\frac \pi2\ .
$$